# Cannot use custom content type as a result source filter in SP2013 O/P

Tags: 2013, search, content-type, document-set, result-source

We have a client with a requirement for a search scope which will only return results of a specific CT - I figured I could do this with a new Result Source but the CT doesn't show in the Query Builder when selecting 'ContentType'

The CT is a site-scoped document set CT - I thought it may be because it's site scoped, not in the content type hub, so I created a new one in the CTB but found the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What query are you using? I suspect that you are not using the correct query. I do this all the time and prefer the approach to using PATH. For example, `ContentType=Contract` will return all of the Contract content type documents.

Comment: Thanks for replying Matt - that's what I'm trying to do, using these values:

Keyword filter = Only return items
Property filter = ContentType
Equals

But the 'Vessel Information' CT doesn't show in the drop down when you click 'Show content types'
Also when I add a CT that does exist it renders it as a hex value, not the text name - is that normal?
In case it's relevant, the CT is part of the site, not the CT hub, and it's a path-based site.

Comment: Also I just tried creating the source at the site's search settings, not in CA (didn't realise you could do this) - the CT shows up fine. I guess if it is a site-scoped CT it'll only show for site-level sources...

Comment: I've found how to add the new RS to the drop down options, only question now is how do I configure the target URL for the drop down to use that result source? When I set it to the search center URL it just returns all results.

Comment: I am confused by your comments. Maybe you can clarify your question. What drop down are you referring to? Where in the UI are you attempting your changes?

Comment: The drop down for the search box - I've got it sorted now, just need to work out with the client if they want it across all sites or on the specific one. Thanks for the help. :)